# Jackson Different Deserialization vs Serlialization Method

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

My Spring Boot API uses camelCase, but I need to proxy some requests through my API to a 3rd party API that uses snake_case. Is it possible to configure Jackson to deserialize the 3rd party response from snake_case, then serialize it back to camelCase to my frontend?

Step by step example of desired functionality:

Example Object:

```
MyObject {
  String myProperty;
}
```

- I call my API
- API calls 3rd Party
- 3rd Party returns

```
{
  "my_property": "my value"
}
```

- My API deserializes it into `MyObject`
- My API serializes the object and returns

```
{
  "myProperty": "my value"
}
```

Right now I am using `@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategies.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)` but of course that will serialize into snake_case as well. Note - even though my api uses camelCase, it would be acceptable to always deserialize from snake_case as this will be a readonly enpoint.

Comment: You could add `@JsonAlias` on the individual properties. You could also configure a different object mapper with an explicit naming strategy for deserialization than for serialization.

Comment: Amazing! This is exactly the functionality I was looking for, and very simple. Please feel free to add an answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add the [`@JsonAlias`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.13/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAlias.html) annotation on the individual properties to add alternative names for deserialization. Or you could configure multiple object mappers with explicit naming strategies, one for deserialization of this third-party API, and one for your normal serialization/deserialization.